# Cómo iniciar dropzone con imagen en base 64

Tags: dropzone

Cómo puedo inicializar dropzone (libreria dropzone.js) con una imagen en base 64 que está en algún div de la página ?

Otra forma de preguntar lo mismo sería cómo puedo inicializar dropzone con cualquier imagen base 64 que tenga ya en la página (no en el servidor) al momento de activar el dropzone ?

Gracias, saludos ...

Comment: a ver si entendi bien buscas que por defecto cargue una imagen en base 64 tu dropzoneJS ?

Comment: Correcto... que al momento de activar el dropzone me cargue una u otra imagen en base 64 que puede estar en localstorage o en algún div .., ocurre que se subirá la imagen por defecto o alguna otra que escoja el usuario... Gracias...